# Many levels rows summing in datatable

Tags: r, loops, data.table, row

I have simple datatable:

```
dt <- data.table(a <- c(1:4), b <- c(11:14))
```

I need sum rows in a loop. For example add second row to first row, later third row to first row, fourth to first. Next step is to add third row to second row and fourth row to second row, later fourth row to third. 
I need to repeat those operations for hundreds of rows.
I know how to make first loop, anyone know how to make second? Or maybe another idea without looping. My first loop:

```
datalist <- list()
  for(i in 2:nrow(dt)){
    datalist[i] =  sum(dt[1, ] + dt[i, ])
  }
```

My desired output,(can be in list, vector, datatable):

```
dt2 <- data.table(d <- c(26,28,30, 30,32, 34))
```

Comment: You should be using vector arithmetic instead of the first loop: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Vector-arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rowSums` then add the first row sum to all other row sums.

```
d <- rowSums(dt)
d[-1] <- d[-1] + d[1]
# [1] 12 26 28 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping, use a rolling/window function like `zoo::rollapply`:

```
library(zoo)

dt <- data.table(a=c(1:4), b=c(11:14))

print(dt)
#    a  b
# 1: 1 11
# 2: 2 12
# 3: 3 13
# 4: 4 14

dt <- transform(dt, expandingSum=rollapply(rowSums(dt),
                                          width=seq(nrow(dt)), sum, align="right"))

print(dt)
#    a  b expandingSum
# 1: 1 11           12
# 2: 2 12           26
# 3: 3 13           42
# 4: 4 14           60
```

The `align` argument orients the window (in this case, `"right"` allows us to look back a certain number of rows). The `width` argument determines how many rows to use in the rolling calculation, so we provide a sequence (here, `seq(nrow(dt))` produces `[1] 1 2 3 4`) so that for each subsequent calculation, the `width` grows by one.

Answer (score 0):

There are two loops outer loop providing row to be added and inner loop is adding the respective row

```
datalist <- c()
k=2
for(j in 1:nrow(dt)){
  if(k < nrow(dt)){
    for(i in k:nrow(dt)){
      print(k)
      a <- sum(sum(dt[j,]),sum(dt[i,]))
      datalist <- c(datalist,a)
    }
  }  
  k=k+1
}
```

Comment: You should [edit] this answer to include an explanation of how it solves the problem. Just posting plain code is not helpful.